# How to fill in file input in a Jinja2 template by image file in memory

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am writing a flask server using Jinja2 template. In a form, I have a file field letting the user to upload an image.

When the form fails validation, the same form will be shown with a flash message. I want the form to be filled with old values, especially the image the user has uploaded. However, I can not figure out how to achieve this.

The object python sent to the Jinja2 template is something like

```
<FileStorage: 'launch-image-3.5@2x.png' ('image/png')>
```

I'm using a macro to render a file input as follows (I'm using Bootstrap 4):

```
{% macro file_uploader(file_name, url_name, title, url) %}

<fieldset class="form-group">
    <strong>{{ title }}</strong>
    <br/>
    <label class="file">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="{{ file_name }}" name="{{ file_name }}">
        <span class="file-custom"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ url_name }}" name="{{ url_name }}" placeholder="{{ title }} URL"
           value="{{ url or '' }}">
    <img id="{{ file_name }}-preview" class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ url or '' }}"
         style="margin-top: 8px; max-width: 50%; display: none;">
</fieldset>

<script>
    $("#{{ file_name }}").on("change", function () {
        $("#{{ url_name }}").val("");
        var input = this;

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var preview = $("#{{ file_name }}-preview");
                preview.attr("src", e.target.result);
                preview.show();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    });
</script>
{% endmacro %}
```

As long as the user upload an image by clicking the input, a preview of the image will be show in the `img` tag.

My problem is, how to programmatically set an image to the file input, such that the `img` tag will be triggered to show the preview, and when the user click submit button, the same image will be again sent to the server within the form.

BTW, my form is a `multipart/form-data` one.

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** do this. Browsers simply do not let you, for good security reasons; obviously, if you can pre-populate a file input, a malicious web page could set it to point to secret data on the client's disk, such as the passwd file.

Comment: I think the asker is talking about initializing the form with a picture that's in memory *on the server*. I don't know if that's doable, but it's not a security risk.

Comment: As @bgschiller says, the webpage is returned from my server, and the file I want to populate in in my server's memory. Is it still a problem?